# Retina background-image css when size is variable?

Tags: css, background-image, retina

Just wondering on something. I'm building out a site header that will have a repeating background image (pattern)

This is simple with something like:

```
background: url(example.com) repeat fixed center;
```

Now I want this to look sharp on high res devices, so normally I would give the image dimensions and create a media query uses an image @2x and sets the width and height them same.

The problem is that I am going to be using several different background images on different pages and they will have different heights and widths.

Is there a way to cover this, save for specifying them all individually?

Cheers.